# UIViewController presents a UINavigationController - no Nav Bar?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have an UIViewController with a table in it. Tapping a blue disclosure icon makes the view controller present a UINavigationController. This works fine and does make the navigation controller show up, but without a navigation bar, as below:

[image] [image]

How would I go about making that magical Navbar showing up again? I really need it to present a map in the nav controller, and right now, that does not work.

**EDIT:** Here's the code I use to show it:

```
// scanned recently table view thing
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableVieww didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableVieww deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
    NSString *info = [[scannedBackups objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSArray *items = [info componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
    scanCodeViewCohntroller.dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    int o;
    for (o = 0; o < [items count]; o++) {
        NSArray *secondItems = [[items objectAtIndex:o] componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        [scanCodeViewCohntroller.dict setObject:[secondItems objectAtIndex:1] forKey:[secondItems objectAtIndex:0]];
        }


        /*NSError *err;
        scanCodeViewCohntroller.dict = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:[foo dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:kCFPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 error:&err];
        if(err != nil) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Corrupted Data" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your Scanned Backup Data Store is corrupted. It will now be erased. %@", [err localizedDescription]] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            scannedBackups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/scannedCodes.plist", documentsDirectory];
            [scannedBackups writeToFile:fullFileName atomically:NO];

        [tableView reloadData];
        }*/
        [scanCodeViewCohntroller.dict setObject:[[scannedBackups objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"] forKey:@"date"];
        [scanCodeViewCohntroller initalizeData];
    [self presentModalViewController:scanCodeViewCohntroller animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be helpful to see the code in your `-tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Are you pushing a new view controller in an existing navigation controller? For completeness sake, it might also be helpful to get some insight as to how you're customizing the navigation bar...

Comment: Sorry, I should have included that, but there it is.

Comment: You're showing the code for selecting a cell, but not the delegate method that gets called when you tap the blue button... Is this what you intended?

Comment: That's basically what that method calls, since both are treated the same. I figured since programmers like me are lazy, 5 lines less code might be a gift to you guys =P

Comment: Let me see if I understand, tapping the body of a cell (the white part) and tapping the blue accessory button both perform the same code? I see that the 'Detail' screen is being present modally. I see no reference to pushing a view controller from an existing navigation controller. If you present a view controller in this way, the navigation bar won't go along for the ride. You'll just have to add a UINavigationBar to the view manually.

Comment: Yes, the view controller was actually pushed when the "Location" cell is tapped in the detail view. When I add the navbar to the actual view, I'm assuming it would not update with the navigation controller, correct?

Comment: I think we're on different pages here, I see no references to any navigation controller in the code you have posted...

Comment: The code to push another view controller is in another file, but it seems as if I managed to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the navigation controller and invoke `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:`. So, try:

```
[detailController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

Edit:

Based on your edit, I would suggest replacing the final line:

```
[self presentModalViewController:scanCodeViewCohntroller animated:YES];
```

with:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:scanCodeViewCohntroller animated:YES];
```

Comment: Quite strangely, this won't fix it. THe navbar will just not appear.

Comment: That does push the view controller onto it, but that view controller is actually encased in an UINavigationController, to which I push a UIViewController with a MapView inside of it. I could probably modify my code to take this.